# How to show data outside foreach in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-8

```
@php         
    $room_feature = explode(",",$row->room_feature);     
@endphp     
@foreach($room_feature as $fetch)         
    @if(!empty($fetch))             
        @php                 
            $keywords[] = getRoomFeatureById($fetch);             
        @endphp         
    @endif     
@endforeach     
@php          
    $record_room = implode(",",$keywords);      
@endphp     
{{ $record_room }}
```

In the above code I want to show all data i.e. `$keywords` outside the foreach. In my database I have value something like `1,2,3,4,5` where I am using `explode` function and I also want to show data something like `A,B,C,D,E` outside the foreach but I have got an error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:`. I don't know why? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `$keywords` is an array, so you can't always just show it like that. You'll want to use [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) to create a nice string, or use another foreach to iterate through it.

Comment: `$keywords` is an array, that's why you get this message. You could for example implode your keywords array (similar to your explode) or instead of putting them in an array you could already add them together in your loop.

Comment: @aynber I love how our sentences start the same.

Comment: ^ Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74264917/edit) and post that as an update; that is unreadable in the comments due to being indented multi-line code.

Comment: @TimLewis code edit please look at once.

Comment: That's better, thanks  It's also a little redundant, when you can just do `{{ implode(', ', $keywords) }}`, but that is beside the point. Does this code work now, or is there still something wrong?

Comment: Yes, this code merge first record with second and first, second with third. something like `A, B`, 2nd record look `A, B, C, D` and 3rd record looks `A, B, C, D, E, F`. where I only want 1st record `A, B` 2nd record `C, D` and 3rd `E, F` like this.

Comment: Well yes, that would happen if you're just continuously appending values to `$keywords` within your `foreach()` loop. If you need them split up, then you'll need to define `$keywords` inside of the `@foreach()`, and output it before you exit the `@endforeach`

Comment: Or, simpler yet, just use `{{ implode(', ', getRoomFeatureById($fetch)) }}` and don't bother with `$keywords` variable at all 

Comment: Literally, just use `{{ implode(', ', getRoomFeatureById($fetch)) }}` instead of `@php $keywords[] = getRoomFeatureById($fetch); @endphp`.

Comment: @TimLewis got this implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: It should be `@if(!empty($fetch)) {{ implode(', ', getRoomFeatureById($fetch)) }} @endif`. If that is _still_ failining, ensure that `getRoomFeatureById` returns an `array` and not `null`, or do `@if(!empty($fetch)) {{ implode(', ', getRoomFeatureById($fetch) ?? []) }} @endif`

Comment: This looks like too much logic in the frontend, to be honest.
I'd suggest that you prepare your data in the backend. This is usually way easier and better to debug as well.